# How to divide time by a constant in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I have an Excel sheet in which I have a column where each cell holds the amount of overtime accumulated since the first row. The format of this cell is `[h]:mm`.

In the column next to it, I want to calculate the number of days this represents (with a working day equal to 07:36). In order to achieve this, I added a column on top holding the 07:36 value in the same format. However, when I enter =AB3/AC1 into a cell, the division gives me an incorrect result.

AB3 holds 19:08, AC1 holds 07:36, the end result of the calculation is 60:25.

In another workbook I have the exact same scenario, but in other cells. The formatting of the cells is the same, yet here the result is correct.

I've tried copying/pasting the formatting of the cells from the correct workbook to the incorrect one, but that doesn't work (the error remains).

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, so my question is: how do I divide a cell which holds a time value (19:08) in the format [h]:mm by a fixed time constant (07:36) in another cell and display the result as a float value (12,25)?

**Edit:** As Paul pointed out in the comments, the result should not be displayed as time, but as a float value (rounded to two decimal places, ideally).

Comment: Minor dimension correction: you're dividing a *time* by a *constant*, the constant being 7:36 hours/day.

Comment: Check whether your cells which contain a time don't happen to include a date as well. You won't see this if you use the [h]:mm format, so change it to date format to check. Additionally, it is meaningless to show your result in a time format, as it will represent a number of working days. (In your example, the result should be 2.52 working days, not two days and 12:25 hours.)

Comment: what is the expected value  for "end result of the calculation"?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes, you are correct, however I would like to have the 7:36 in a separate cell since the value could possibly change. That's why I initially asked to divide time by time, but it's a constant indeed.

Comment: @Paul I've converted each cell to dd/mm/jjjj uu:mm (our Dutch representation of day/months/year hour:minute) and all cells show the same date: 01/01/1904 (hh:mm), except for the calculated value which shows 03/01/1904 (hh:mm). 
And obviously it's meaningless to display the result as a time, it should indeed be a value representing x working days, thanks for pointing it out, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @p._phidot_ As Paul pointed out, the result should be a float value indicating the number of working days in this example, and not a time. I've edited my question.
The exact result in this case would be 2,51754386, but it would preferably be rounded to 2,52.

Comment: @joe there's your answer: the correct result is 2.52, which if you format it in hours and minutes is about 60:25 (two days = 48 hours, .5 day = 12 hours).

Comment: @Paul I don't know what to say, I cannot believe I didn't spot that... I was probably too confused by the different formats (time in one sheet vs float in the other) to realise the value was actually correct. Anyway, thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad 2hear that.. /(^_^)\

Comment: @Joe  , if AB3 is 19:08 and  AC1 is 7:36 and using formula AB3/AC1 then u get 12:25 ,,, initially you get `2.5175439`  apply an appropriate TIME format,,, other than [h]:mm ,,,  U get `12:25` ,,better use `hh:mm` ☺!!